# Скрытие полосы у NavigationPage

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

У меня есть обычная страница ContentPage. Я создал команду(соблюдаю MVVM) перехода на новую страницу(MasterDetailPage):

```
await navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new MenuPage()));
```

Я специально вызываю модальную страницу, чтобы не было кнопки возвращения назад. Переход происходит успешно. Однако, отображается страница так:
[image]

Я решил скрыть бар навигации:

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

Это я вызываю в конструкторе новой страницы (masterdetailpage отображает свое свойство Detail, там установлена обычная страница ContentPage). В результате вывод изменился на такой:
[image]

Как видно, скрылось совсем не то.. Как верно скрыть синюю полосу? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему установкой новой страницы как родительской:

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new MenuPage();
```